# MatLab Daubechies Filter of colored picture form ground up - not using preset functions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, wavelet, haar-wavelet

this is my first post. I hope someone can help me getting started. So I've been working on image processing for a class project. We started out easy by creating a Haar transform function from scratch, which was pretty straight forward and then applying it to preset pictures such as cameraman.tif. However, that sample picture is on a grayscale and a square matrix.

Now we made a big leap and we're supposed to apply the filter to any rectangular colored picture. I understand that if I `imread(picture)` it will create an array matrix with three values representing red, green and blue (RGB). I also understand that principally speaking I have to use a `for` loop to go through each channel of color. However, it trips me on how to create it for the different channels and put the image back together.

I went through some awesome answers here and was able to reconstruct the woman and [fruit basket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766210/matlab-wavelet-transform-for-n-dimensionmodified?rq=1), but unfortunately they all use the preset `DWT` function, which I must not.

The final code should go like: 
1)Ask the user how many iterations are desired:

```
pic =   input('What picture would you like? Type "1" for an example or a URL  ');
```

2) Ask the user about the threshold

```
t   =   input('Threshold?');
```

3) Ask the user how many iterations (1-3)

```
i   =   input('How many iterations do you want? Choose 1-3.  ');
```

As a sample image, I chose a rectangular bitmap, because it hasn't been compressed yet and using "1" as an easy identifier:

```
if pic ==1;
   A = imread ('http://readingeagle.com/BlogUploads/11/Birds%20in.bmp');
else A = imread(pic) ;
end

%[m,n]=Matrix dimensions, c=channels
[m,n,c]=size (A) ; 

%plot original
imshow (A);
```

Now we have to perform the Daubchechies Wavelet Transform with however many iterations the user specified while setting the values outside of the Threshold's absolute value to zero. Before reconstructing the image.

I hope I gave enough information, please correct me if I went wrong already (I hope not). MY code starts breaking every time I implement loops and try to address the channels. Just for reference purposes here is the Haar transform that worked for the original cameraman.tif image:

```
%HWTM - Haar Wavelet Transform Matrix

function W = HWTM(N)

while mod(N,2) ~= 0;
    N = N-1;
end 

W=zeros(N);
for k=1:N/2
    W(k,2*k)=1/2;
    W(k,2*k-1)=1/2;
    W(N/2+k,2*k)=1/2;
    W(N/2+k,2*k-1)=-1/2;
end
end
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Which error message do you get? Also we'd need to see the code that actually breaks!